# Oracle ADF Faces application on Websphere 7.0

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, websphere-7

Can someone please help me out with the Oracle ADF faces application which I'm trying to deploy on Websphere 7.0? Do I need to apply any fixpacks on WAS? I'm trying to migrate this project from Websphere 6.1 to Websphere 7.0.

In Websphere 6.1, after removing jsf implementation jar files and providing them as part of WEB-INF\lib and changing the classloader to PARENT_LAST, the application was working fine.

For websphere 7.0, I can't seem to get the application working. It always picks up the Sun's JSF implementation. I've also tried the shared library concept but to no success.

Regards,
Zahir

Answer (score 0):

The [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdev11gr2-cert-405181.html#Application_Servers) lists a certification for WAS 7.0.0.13 ND. So you need FixPack 13 or later.

As the WebSphere Application Server 7 is a full blown [JEE5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee5-jsp-135162.html) server it requires/has JSF 1.2 support. You can switch between the built in Sun and MyFaces implementation if required.

You should probably make sure that the ADF version you are using is certified for WAS 7. The [ADF release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/jdev-11gr2-nf-404365.html) tell that ADF supports JSF 2.0. The WAS 7 only comes with JSF 1.2. Exchanging the JSF version with placing the JSF 2 libs into `WEB-INF/lib` works well for our projects in conjunction with the 'PARENT_LAST' classloading policy. Make sure that you set the policy either for the whole application or for both the application and the web module.

Answer (score 0):

ADF Faces is a Java based framework and it will run on WebSphere but, you have to add the required libraries first. The easiest way to prepare WebSphere to run ADF Faces application is through JDeveloper. Alternatively, you can google Oracle JRF (Java Runtime Framework) and install that on your WebSphere, before running the ADF Faces application.